# How can I add an image to cover my bootstrap card(s)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've made a bootstrap card and added an image in the css which covers the whole bootstrap card. Now I want to add on my bootstrap so that I can allow the users to change it when they. I've tried doing a couple of ways but the image doesn't cover the whole card. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="content">
        <h2 class="title">To The Beach</h2>
        <p class="copy">Plan your next beach trip with these fabulous destinations</p>
        <button class="btn">View Trips</button>
        <img src="camera.jpg" class="card-img-fluid">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this in your card-body section

```css
.cardBackground{
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url('https://www.rockaxis.com/img/newsList/2640462.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="card w-50">
    <div class="card-body cardBackground">
        <h2 class="card-title">To The Beach</h2>
        <p class="copy card-text">Plan your next beach trip with these fabulous destinations</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">View Trips</button>
        <img src="camera.jpg" class="card-img-fluid">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm avoiding using css, because I'm making a cms type of system.